# Extremely slow VPN connection between Windows 10 client and Windows 2008 R2 Server

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, vpn, rras, windows-10

After a bit of hassle setting up and configuring my VPN connection on Windows 10, I finally got it connecting to our Windows 2008 R2 server using RRAS.

When establishing the connection, it connects extremely quickly, but upon connecting to file shares, browsing is slow and opening/transferring files can be painfully slow.

Below are some of my current settings on both the Client and Server. If anyone has any ideas on how to potentially decrease lag in the connection I'd appreciate it.

Questions:
Can/should I tweak TCP settings on the server?
Can/should I tweak settings on the client(s)?

**Current Server Settings (Win Server 2008 R2):**

- TCP Window Auto-Tuning: normal
- Windows Scaling Heuristics: disabled
- Congestion Control Provider: ctcp
- RSS: enabled
- TCPA: enabled
- DCA: disabled
- TTL:
- ECN Capability: disabled
- Checksum Offloading: default: n/a
- TCP Chimney Offload: automatic
- TCP1323 Options:
- Window Scaling: unchecked
- Timestamps: unchecked

**Current client Settings (Win 10):**

- TCP Window Auto Tuning: normal
- Windows Scaling Heuristics: disabled
- Congestion Control Provider: ctcp
- RSS:
- RSC:
- DCA:
- TTL:
- ECN Capability: disabled
- Checksum Offloading:
- TCP Chimney Offload:
- LSO:
- TCP 1323 Timestamps: disabled

Things I have tried:

- Turning on Window Scaling
- Disabling Offloading features (TCP/RSS/Chimney)

I'm new to VPN connections, so any help would be appreciated, or if there are any tests that I should run on the connection please let me know.

Comment: I had originally asked this question at Super User, but was told that I might have more luck finding help here.

Comment: You're browsing Windows shares over the internet via a VPN connection, that's just not going to perform well. Tweaking a bunch of network related settings isn't likely to help.

Comment: @joeqwerty - I am, but I've been told that I should be getting 70-80% throughput of my available connection. My server is 80+Mbps Up/Down, and my client is 200Mbps Down/25 Mbps Up. When doing file uploads, I'm only seeing about 350 KB/s upload from client to server (which is less than 10% of what's available). Unless I'm missing something.